# Oracle Trigger create with compilation errors

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I wrote the below trigger to prevent users from allocating a Class to a Session if the Class Date does not match the day of the week the Session is on.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig_alternative_classDate
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON ALTERNATIVE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    classdate CHAR;
    sessionday VARCHAR;
BEGIN
    SELECT to_char(to_date(class.class_date), 'Day') INTO classdate, sessions.day INTO sessionday
    FROM SESSIONS, CLASS, DUAL, LOCATION, ALTERNATIVE
    WHERE class.class_id = alternative.class_id
    AND alternative.location_id = location.location_id
    AND sessions.location_id = location.location_id;
    IF sessions.day != to_char(to_date(class.class_date), 'Day')
    THEN raise_application_error(-20999,'Invalid Class Date - Class Date does not match Session Day');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

However I get an error message when I run the trigger

```
Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

SQL> show error trigger trig_alternative_classDate
Errors for TRIGGER TRIG_ALTERNATIVE_CLASSDATE:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
5/2  PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
5/80 PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove second INTO - only one INTO is needed:

```
INTO classdate, sessions.day INTO sessionday
```

Comment: @Ben Townsend - Did you try? Works?